# Ajax ActionLink does not work when css class active and jQuery is applied

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
<ul style="padding-right:1px;" class="navigation">
            <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Dashboard", "Dashboard", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "detailContainer", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class="active"})</li>
            <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Cases", "Cases", "Cases", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "detailContainer", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })</li>
            <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Reports", "Report", "Reports", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "detailContainer", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })</li>
        </ul>

<div class="col-xs-10" id="detailContainer">
    @Html.Action("Dashboard", "Dashboard")
</div>
```

I have `<ul>` like above. You can see on first

I have applied `class='active'` which works fine. But when I click on **Dashboard**after navigating from other `<li>` element, `Ajax.ActionLink` doesn't open Dashboard view. The problem seems to be with jQuery script. I have applied following JQuery to change `class='active'` when `<li><a>` is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selector = '.navigation li a';
    $(selector).click(function () {
        $(selector).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

But when I remove `class='active'` from Dashboard, navigation works fine but when I apply `class` it doesn't open Dashboard view.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using correct method. There is no overloaded method as `ActionLink(AjaxHelper, String, String, String, AjaxOptions, Object)`

Use [`AjaxExtensions.ActionLink(AjaxHelper, String, String, String, Object, AjaxOptions, Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions,System.Object%29)

```
 <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Dashboard", "Dashboard", null, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "detailContainer", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class="active"})</li>
```

Comment: O yes, my bad. Thanks Satpal